# update multiple documents of specific field values based on _Id

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

i have the two sample documents as :

```
[
        {
            "_id": "605b2fcb526b8b609ef97eaa",
            "comments": "",
            "name": "",
            "user_name": ""
        },
        {
            "_id": "605b3034asubc2bed542f88f",
            "comments": "",
            "name": "",            
            "user_name": ""
        }   
]
```

and the updated data for these two documents for key `comment` i have as :

```
[
        {
            "_id": "605b2fcb526b8b609ef97eaa",
            "comments": "test one",
            "name": "",
            "user_name": ""
        },
        {
            "_id": "605b3034asubc2bed542f88f",
            "comments": "test two",
            "name": "",            
            "user_name": ""
        }       
]
```

Here I am currently trying using a loop by `ID` and update the respective `comment value` using `update`

May i know how could i use `update_many` in this scenario ?

Any guiding links or a solution is much appreciated TIA

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can update different values to the same field in different documents in a single query to Mongo (update_many or otherwise).
You need to use a loop or you can do a [Bulk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/).

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation mate , surfed a lot but got same info